How to transpose an excel file using Power Automate?
So, this is the format my file is in right now -

And this is how I want this to be -

I am using the website version and am new to Power Automate. I tried to make a flow but I don't know how to proceed or what to do.

I tried finding solutions online but couldn't find any.
Can someone here help please?

Look at using Office Scripts.

Can't, I am told to use Power Automate only.

Office Scripts is a part of the PowerAutomate family. Have you asked those who are governing your solution?

There is an action in power automate to run a script in excel, and it should be fairly simple
